# Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD fails to boot on a Dell XPS 17 (L702X)

Tags: 12.04, boot, kernel, dell, live-cd

I'm currently running Ubuntu 11.10, upgraded from version 11.04. I'd like to "refresh" my system by reinstalling with Ubuntu 12.04.

Unfortunately, I get a kernel panic when trying to boot the LiveCD with the error "not syncing: VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)".

I have md5ed the disc, and it was burned correctly. I'm using the 64-bit Desktop version, though I'll try the alternate version tomorrow.

I have tried common workarounds like acpi=off, but still can't get past the kernel panic.

The important system specs:

- Processor: i7 quad core
- Graphics: Intel + Nvidia 555M (optimus)
- Hard drive: 2x 500GB
- Bios: running latest A17 version from Dell

I'd be glad to file a bug report, but I'm not sure where the problem lies. Anyone having similar problems or a workaround to try?

UPDATE: For anyone reading this, the alternative CD works for me, so I suggest using that instead.